# como criar um video do youtube em tela cheia com botão de voltar?

Tags: jquery, html5, youtube

Galera, preciso criar um player em meu site, que ao clicar no botão assistir, o mesmo abra em tela cheia e contenha um botão "voltar" para o usuário voltar a home.
Seria possível fazer isso usando o player do youtube?

Comment: O código embed do youtube já não faz isso?

Comment: Está usando Bootstrap? você pode abrir um modal do tamanho que quiser com o codigo embed do video no youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, tem como você simular a tela cheia da seguinte forma:

No HTML você cria uma estrutura de template que será utilizado dentro de uma janela modal:

```
<script type="text/template" id="video_1">
<iframe width="100%" height="720px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LGApONHq8LI?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<a href="link voltar"> Voltar</a>
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="video" data-id="1">Vídeo</a>
```

depois você cria a estrutura da modal:

```
<div id="modal_video"></div>
```

Eu não criei a modal, somente coloquei o vídeo em uma div para ter uma idéia.

jQuery:

```
$('.video').click(function(){
    var idVideo = $(this).data('id');
    var video = $('#video_'+idVideo).html();
    $('#modal_video').html(video);
});
```

O link voltar você pode mudar para fechar já que o usuário não sairá da página, apenas fechará a modal.
segue o exemplo do funcionamento: https://jsfiddle.net/vsytwd7e/

Answer (score 0):

Nessa maneira o video abre em outra janela, ocupando todo o espaço da mesma, assim se o usuario quer voltar ao site é so fecha-la, não creio que haja metodo de automaticamente abrir em fullscreen porque seria invasivo ao usuario.

```html
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/v/GsF1jnTjRLo?autoplay=1" target="_blank">assistir</a>
```

o `https://www.youtube.com/v/GsF1jnTjRLo`

é diferente do  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsF1jnTjRLo`

justamente porque o primeiro ocupa a pagina toda, e o segundo vai para o link no youtube